# How to use a single QLineEdit multiple times in qt for editing a different label each time?

Tags: qt

I am new to qt. I want to edit 10 labels based on the 10 given inputs from a single QLineEdit, one after the other.

Initially, when I enter some text in the line-edit, label1 should be edited as given text. Similarly, the second time when I enter some text, only label2 should be edited as given text and so on.

I have tried the following:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed() {
int change=0;
QString input1,input2,input3;
switch(change) {
case 0:  input1 = ui->lineEdit->text();
         ui->label_11->setText(input1);
         change=1;
         break;
case  1: input2 = ui->lineEdit->text();
         ui->label_12->setText(input2);
         change=2;
         break;
case  2: input3 = ui->lineEdit->text();
         ui->label_13->setText(input3);
         change=3;
         break; }
```

}

Here, every time i enter some input through the QLineEdit, only label_11 is getting updated.

My question remains: **How can I use a single QLineEdit multiple times to edit different labels each time?**

Comment: You need to keep track which label you want to update, yourself. Simple as that. There's no "magic" which would make this just happen. Add a state variable, then use swtich-case or if-elseif-else ladder, which ever you feel more comfortable with. If you have trouble getting it to work, use debugger, set breakpoint to this slot and step through it.

Comment: It seems like you didn't get my point. Even after trying your suggestion only the 1st label is getting updated every time I enter the input from QLineEdit. Following is the code:

Comment: void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed() {            
    int change=0;                      
    QString input1,input2,input3;
    switch(change) {              
    case 0:  input1 = ui->lineEdit->text();
             ui->label_11->setText(input1);
             change=1;
             break;            
    case  1: input2 = ui->lineEdit->text();
             ui->label_12->setText(input2);
             change=2;
             break;         
    case  2: input3 = ui->lineEdit->text();
             ui->label_13->setText(input3);
             change=3;
             break; }}

Comment: sorry it is not allowing me to type more than 600 characters in a single comment.

Comment: _sorry it is not allowing me to type more than 600 characters in a single comment._ Yeah. You shouldn't do this. If your question needs clarification, please, use the [edit] link (under the tags) to update your question.

Comment: And, btw. the hint of hyde sounds very reasonable to me. How about an array to store the addresses of labels? Then the extra state could be an index to select the current label from this array.

Comment: Ok i have updated my question... And my problem is that second time when i enter some text ,after editing first label ,again only the first label is getting edited!  see, here in my code, initial value of "change" is 0 so case 0 gets executed and after editing the first label, "change" is updated to 1. So next time when I enter text in linedit, case 1 should be executed since value of change is 1 which is not happening here!!!  Every time only the case 0 is getting executed..

Comment: Hint: try making `change` a member of `MainWindow`.

Comment: woah!  G.M. you just saved my life with a single line!!!  Thank you so much guys for spending your valuable time on my silly question!!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "change" is local in function. It is turned to 0 every time slot engages. You should make this variable a class member to store it's value.

Answer (score 0):

you should move "change" variable to mainwindow.h and make it global variable  instate of local variable

mainwindow.h

```
public:
    int change ;
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ...
    change = 0;
}
```

by this changes, the amount of variable will be save in every call in    on_lineEdit_returnPressed